What do I do if my professor doesn't give me an extra credit assignment that he promised?
The problem is this: I'm taking an online course, and my professor told everyone that there will be an extra credit assignment at the end of my course. Not just me, but for the whole class. The extra credit appeared Monday on the dashboard, saying it will be due on Sunday (as is with all other assignments in my course). However, although it is unlocked, there are no problem/explanation or any assignment description at all. Originally I thought there's some system error or he just got sloppy and forgot, but today is already Wednesday and he still hasn't added the description. Well, I know this is a rather minor issue, but I still wish to ask for recommendations here. What should I do? The extra credit is not some sudden extra chance for failing student, but actually stated in the syllabus at the start of the course. If appears to me that it had been a long-time legacy of this course, and I don't see any reason for it to suddenly be gone. Even if he changed his mind and doesn't want to be generous, he should've at least give some kind of notification to tell us all that there'd be no extra credit. I'm thinking about sending an email to asking him about the issue, but I'm not sure if he'll just get mad or ignore me altogether. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

You are getting good answers. Politeness is always the right approach. A mistake is more likely than anything else. On the other hand some teachers are offended at having mistakes pointed out (even if it is not their mistake but a system error). So just in case, for insurance, take a screenshot of everything you see.

"...today is already Wednesday and he still hasn't added the description". Why would he add a description if he doesn't know it's missing? Has anybody informed him that the assignment doesn't have any content?

"I'm thinking about sending an email to asking him about the issue, but I'm not sure if he'll just get mad or ignore me altogether." You've already reasoned your way through to the correct conclusion here. The idea that maybe he'll "just get mad" for no reason seems like a completely random, groundless concern that you should simply discard (unless your professor has a history of getting mad for no reason).

Just email the professor!  One of my biggest frustrations with students recently is that they seem terrified of emailing their instructors, and are much more likely to attempt to get advice from a bunch of total strangers on Reddit or SE.  Your instructor almost certainly wants you to be successful; internet strangers don't care.  Just email them!

@jeguyer I don't actually know if other students asked about this, because I'm taking an online course and there are no live zoom meeting discussions or the like. But I don't think they had asked because most of them seems to be too occupied with this week's regular homework that they don't have time to ask or even to check.

@AdamPřenosil Thanks for pointing out, my professor don't have a history of getting mad for no reason, so probably I'll just ask him, just like everyone here suggested. Thanks for all the help, everyone!

Some LMS platforms (looking at you, Blackboard!) are notoriously finicky, it's possible your professor doesn't know how to use the software all that well and has screwed something up.

It's probably best just to send him a politely worded email, short and to the point. You (and we) can't know what the professor's reaction will be but your request for clarification seems legitimate. Maybe it's a misunderstanding on your part or an oversight on his. Just ask.

This. And word it as your mistake not the profs, so “I’m having trouble accessing XYZ; what am I doing wrong?” not “You messed up uploading the extra credit assignment”.


Double check with yourself that you don't miss anything obvious/Are looking in the right place.

Double check with a fellow student (if you know them/are in touch)

E-mail the professor that you have done 1 and 2 but cannot seem to find the assignment, express your enthusiasm about doing the assignment and ask them for instructions on how to proceed. Keep it short and polite and 9 out of 10 they accidentally made a mistake.


